# The Terrestar Genus was able to talk to a GEO satellite in a smartphone-sized package, where's the antenna on this thing?

Tags: antenna, satellites, microwave

## Background

I'm doing some research on a company called ASTS who claims to be able to connect to regular smartphones from a satellite. Initially I wrote off their claims, but after looking into it a bit more ([along with some link budget calculations](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/55143/is-it-possible-for-leo-satellites-to-detect-a-usable-signal-from-regular-mobile)), it actually seemed... surprisingly possible.

To my surprise, this wasn't even actually the first time this has been done. Apparently a company called TerreStar was able to connect to a smartphone back in 2010, from GEO! I've always imagined satellite phones to be big, bulky, power-hungry devices.

Out of curiosity I bought a used TerreStar Genus to take apart, just to see how big the antenna is - especially since it's talking to a GEO satellite. I'm having trouble locating it though, can anyone help?

So far I found some rf amplifiers, but not the actual antennas themselves...

**SKY65124-21** - RF Amplifier 1930-1990MHz 2W 5Volt -40C +85C

**SKY77340-21** - The SKY77340 Power Amplifier Module (PAM) is designed in a compact form factor for quad-band cellular handsets comprising GSM850/900, DCS1800, PCS1900, supporting GMSK and linear EDGE modulation.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

More pictures here (and also available upon request): https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJ1cv.jpg

## Updated Question

Wait, I think I found them! Are these it? Wow, I'm honestly shocked these tiny things are able to transmit to GEO. Is the antenna that's connecting to the satellite the `E000118 REV F` one since that's the only one that's above the line?

Going by the 2 rf amplifiers I found, does this mean that the antenna had a max output of 2W?

[image]

Comment: Assuming 1950MHz, back of the envelope calculations is a quarter wavelength would be ~3.9cm? Though, antenna design gets really strange at these frequencies. Anyway, feel free to self-answer if you think you found 'em.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see five rf connections to off-board antennas, all around the board. Each connection has a "hot" and a ground, because the antennas are variations of the [Inverted F antenna](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted-F_antenna). Most of the antenna PCBs look like FR4, which is not ideal.

The satellite antenna is probably the thing in the centre of the back shell just below the camera hole, above number 21 on your cutting pad in the second photo. This is the prime antenna position.

It makes contact with the two spring contacts on the right of the board, below the alert/vibrate motor. Note how there is no ground cut-out below these two contacts, unlike all the other antennas, so the back centre antenna must be a different design.

**Edit** Maybe that's a loudspeaker. It looks like it from some intact phone photos. Though the traces connecting to it are quite RF-like, they wouldn't bother doing that for a speaker?
[image]

If it is the monopole/IFA called E000118 then another clue is that the RF trace to the external antenna connector runs all the way around the camera and down to nearby the same RF can.

Inmarsat isatphone is a handheld phone using GEO satellites. It's been around since before 2010. It has a flip-up quadrafilar helix antenna and uses an amazing 2400bps voice CODEC. Thuraya is another GEO-based service, satellites at 44 and 98 longitude only.

Cellphones long ago traded antenna performance for form factor, but when gain, pattern and circular polarisation really counts they go back to a big external antenna.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the middle part is for the loud speaker. I was pretty confused too when I saw the giant contacts going to a speaker.

What are PCB FR4 antennas, and why aren't they ideal though?

Comment: @0xbad1d3a5 FR4 is a type of PCB material. It's very common to print microwave antennas on them.

Comment: If you look closely, both the earphone at the top is covered by the same mesh. That thing in the back is probably a piezo speaker, and the connects are typical spring-pin connectors used in plastic handset construction. Perhaps the antenna is the round silver thing in the middle of the ground-plan. It says "06P" or "d90" depending on how you want to read it. That would be the size, orientation, and location of a stubby coil antenna we often see on high-freq stuff.

Comment: That being said, just searching for "s-band antenna" will show you so-called "patch" antennas that look pretty much like that "speaker". Circularly polarized antennas. They also come in little covered stubby coils too, so the mystery is not over.

Comment: I was wrong. That stubby thing is the vibration device. The silver thingy with the spring-pins is an s-band patch antenna.

Comment: I worked in a cell phone factory in the late nineties, when the phones we were making had antennas about 10 cm (4") long that could be extended or retracted.  Extending the antenna improved reception by about 4 dB (which was less than one bar on the display).  That was when mobile phone networks were in their infancy, and cell site antennas in cities were mounted up high.  Now cellular antennas in cities are mounted down low to limit the number of users connected to the site, which is much closer now.  Handset antenna gain doesn't matter nearly as much now as it did back then, as you say.

Comment: Yes until you need to talk to a satellite :) All satellite phones I've seen have external QHA antennas that can be adjusted vertical. @0xbad1d3a5 FR4 is 10 to 100x more lossy than better materials, usually antennas are "printed" on a plastic part (eg Nokia 3110) or made on microwave board. The net effect on an IFA is probably ~1 dB which is equivalent to 25% longer talk time.

Comment: This device had an optional external antenna. You can see the input for it near the camera, which the antenna would cover when installed.

Comment: @jdv yes but would that be the GSM antenna or the satellite? Probably satellite, right? If you follow the RF trace back to the shielded block, the corresponding internal antenna must be the upper true-right green E000118. So perhaps this *is* the satellite antenna then. I also think the "loudspeaker" grille might be a decoy. Loudspeakers, even in 2010, are PCB mounted, 12x10x3 mm. And the traces feeding the "loudspeaker" are too fancy to be just for audio. Then the external connector is for GSM or GPS or something else.

Comment: Hmm. The manual says "Using an external antenna - You can use an external antenna to improve the strength of the satellitesignal. Tap (windows) > Settings > Connections > External Antenna to beingenabling the external antenna for satellite calls. Amazon has [a listing](https://www.amazon.com/TerreStar-Networks-External-Sled-Antenna-Frustration-Free-Packaging-Black/dp/B004Z77R6O) for an external antenna, it's definitely for the satellite. So I think this, with the trace, settles the internal antenna question.

Comment: @tomnexus The external antenna was for satellite. At least, according to the review/blurb I found online. It covered the camera when installed. I see what you mean about that "Rev F" trace. It does look like something of interest. The "speaker" thingy does look like a patch antenna if you search vendors for "s-band" antennas. More mystery!

Comment: I don't think the speaker thing is a patch antenna, unless the white metal part inside is also being used as an antenna as well as powering the speaker. The port for the external antenna is the gold circular ring by the camera. The external antenna also wasn't needed for satellite connectivity, only to improve the signal. Here's more shots of those areas: https://imgur.com/a/xiqel7U